# getting error[ invalid session id] during hitting same url multiple times

Tags: python

getting below error.

consol output

```
@pytest.mark.perf123
def test_LoadTime(self):
    self.lt = LoadTime(self.driver)
    self.driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
    time.sleep(10)
    timer1 = self.lt.pageLoad()
    self.driver.close()
    print(timer1)
    self.driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
```

**selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid session id**

### here first time web site opened successfully and getting error at second time.

Code for reference.

```
@pytest.mark.perf123
def test_LoadTime(self):
    self.lt = LoadTime(self.driver)
    self.driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
    time.sleep(10)
    timer1 = self.lt.pageLoad()
    self.driver.close()
    print(timer1)
    self.driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
    time.sleep(10)
    timer2 = self.lt.pageLoad()
    self.driver.close()
    print(timer2)
    self.driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
    time.sleep(10)
    timer3 = self.lt.pageLoad()
    self.driver.close()
    print(timer3)
    timer = (timer1+timer2+timer3)/3.0
    print(timer)
```

---

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def setupone(request):
  browser = request.config.getoption("browser_name")
  env_name = request.config.getoption("env")
  product = request.config.getoption("product_name")
  dict = getData(product)
  if browser == "PerfChrome" and env_name == "Production":
      options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
      options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
      capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
      capabilities['goog:loggingPrefs'] = {"performance": "ALL"}
      driver = SeleneDriver.wrap(webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities, 
    executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=options))
    request.cls.product = product
    request.cls.driver = driver
    yield
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).